# I want to change the position of Kivy Mapview by pressing the button but I get error message

Tags: python, kivy

```
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import Color
from kivy.graphics.instructions import InstructionGroup
from kivy.graphics.vertex_instructions import Line
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy_garden.mapview import MapView, MapMarker
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = '''

MyMapView:
    zoom: 2
    double_tap_zoom: True
    id: gps
    Button:
        text: " [86-6] "
        background_color: (1,1,1,1)
        color: (0,0,0,1)
        font_size: 15
        size_hint: (None,None)
        width: 150
        height: 30
        on_press: root.gpss()
'''

class MyMapView(MapView):
    grp = ObjectProperty(None)


    def gpss(self):
        self.ids.gps.lat = 48.20753856396109 
        self.ids.gps.lon = 16.372519189874197

class MapViewApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)



MapViewApp().run()
```

`Error`

```
     self.ids.gps.lat = 48.20753856396109 
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 864, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
[Finished in 5.0s with exit code 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your use of `ids`. The `ids` of a kivy object are a dictionary to objects in the widget tree below the root. But the only `id` you have assigned in your `kv` is for the root node itself. So, no `ids` are actually added to the `ids` dictionary. That is what causes the error message (the `ids` dictionary is empty). But since your `gpss()` is a method of the `MyMapView` object, you don't need to use `ids` to get a reference to it, it is simply `self`. So your `gpss()` method can be changed to:

```
def gpss(self):
    self.lat = 48.20753856396109
    self.lon = 16.372519189874197
    self.zoom = 20
```

You may need to add something like a `zoom` setting to get the `MapView` to respond

Comment: Thank you very much sr